# Show text auto type in background in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show a text that will be look like automatically text was writing in the background and the popup will be shown. But the popup does not affect the background text.

I am using following code:-

```
    function changeText(cont1,cont2,speed){
        var Otext=cont1.text();
        var Ocontent=Otext.split("");
        var i=0;

        function show(){
            if(i<Ocontent.length)
            {       
            cont2.append(Ocontent[i]);
            i=i+1;
            };
        };
        var text=setInterval(show,speed); 
    };
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('test alert box');
        var p=changeText($("p"),$(".p2"),150);
        clearInterval(p);
    });`

   ` <p>sjdhhsfsdufvudyvdyvc</p>
    <p class="p2"></p>
        p {display: none;font-size: 25px;}
        .p2 {display: block; float: left;height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;       width: 400px;
                         word-break: break-all;margin: 30px 0 0 30px;}`
```

above code is working but when popup comes out it stops working. I want the text should work even when popup was shown.

Comment: What popup? There is no popup code shown. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: i have updated the code.. i just want to show simple alert box